# Restarting the Thymleaf view resolver at runtime in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

By default the view resolvers are loaded during app startup and the bean is stored in springs application context.

I have a template (html) file in my default directory which is translated by the view resolver to the view.This gets loaded properly after I start the application

I now want to dynamically add more templates(html) files at run time using a POST api with the template(html) file name and the html file.
I can add the files in the directory along with the name,but the problem is that the spring does not load that html which has been added by me since the VIEW RESOLVER is initialized during app startup. How can I change the behavior of View Resolver to load again if I add a html file without redeploying the war.

I have tried to get the bean of View Resolver at runtime and searched for methods like restart,reboot which I was not able to find.

It only starts resolving the template(html) which I had uploaded when I redeploy the war which I cant do for every request to the controller.

Comment: Did you try with setting property `spring.thymeleaf.cache: false` in `application.properties`? I don't know if it is caching files or compiled templates.

Comment: Yes  I tried.
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false is used to disable caching of existing templates. It does not add new templates to the template resolver

Comment: Have you tried using another TemplateResolver? E.g. `org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.FileTemplateResolver` ?